# Как указать новый url в браузере, который динамически меняется?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Вот есть url 
www.site/page/1

Загрузилась страница, а там таблица и в таблице строка 1 стала активная. 
Затем в этой таблице я выбрал другую строку с id 2 (через ajax).

Однако ссылка осталась старой 
site/page/1

И при обновлении страницы мы снова попадем на строку 1, а надо запоминать и вставать на строку 2.

Как это сделать?

Comment: `history.pushState` - даст возможность изменить адрес и заголовок страницы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 History Api вам в помощь ( https://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/ )

Пример:

```
history.pushState({}, "", "/page/1");
```

Answer (score 0):

В cookie можно сохранять номер активной строки
А при открытии брать номер строки из этого cookie